# How to switch to python2 in a particular terminal window temporarily?

Tags: python, linux

I have a big third-party python2.7 application, a bunch of python scripts, which is added into `PATH` and it requires python2.7 instead of python 3.5 which I have by default.

```
$ python
Python 3.5.1 (default, Mar  3 2016, 09:29:07) 
[GCC 5.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 


$ python2
Python 2.7.11 (default, Mar  3 2016, 11:00:04) 
[GCC 5.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

I run that application as `$ some_app arg1 arg2`. How can make it use python2 as a temporary solution, preferably only in that single terminal window?

I don't substitute a call of that application with "python". I call it like `$ some_app arg1 arg2`. I don't want to change the version of python permanently or modify the source code of the application.

Comment: `python2 /path/to/some_app arg1 arg2`?

Comment: is this application a Python script (does it have something like `#!/usr/bin/env python` in the first line)?

Comment: Would adding `#!/usr/bin/env python2.7` help you ? Or perhaps just calling from the terminal `python2.7 app arg1 arg2`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select which version of python I am running on Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35047691/how-to-select-which-version-of-python-i-am-running-on-linux)

Answer (score 5):

## My favorite way: use virtualenv or pyenv

The most used tool for keeping multiple Python environments is [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/). I like to use a sugary wrapper around it called [virtualenvwrapper](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Usually I install it using:

```
sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

Then I add a line like the following one to my shell profile:

```
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Now you can make a virtual environment for each version of Python. Gosh, you can make one for each Python project!

```
mkvirtualenv py3
mkvirtualenv py2 --python=python2
```

Then you can switch temporarily to python2 by typing:

```
workon py2
```

There is another tool called [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv) that lets you easily switch between multiple versions of Python. Quoting the project readme, "It's simple, unobtrusive, and follows the UNIX tradition of single-purpose tools that do one thing well. This project was forked from rbenv and ruby-build, and modified for Python". Looks like it is getting popular.

Both are elegant, easy to use and a perfect fit for this use case (switch to a particular python version in a terminal window temporarily).

## The Unix way: set `$PATH`

It is a best practice to write the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) for Python scripts like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

If the 3rd-party app you are running follows this convention, you can change the PATH. For example, suppose the default python interpreter is not the one you want:

```
$ env python --version
Python 3.5.1
```

Make a local copy of the python you want to make the default temporarily (you just have to do this one time):

```
$ mkdir ~/local
$ mkdir ~/local/python2
$ ln -s `which python2` ~/local/python2/python
```

Then every time you want to make python2 the default, do:

```
$ export PATH=~/local/python2/:$PATH
```

Now the default is the version you want:

```
$ env python --version
Python 2.7.10
```

## The positive karma way: if the 3rd-party app has a hardcoded path in the shebang

Perhaps the app author did not follow the best practices and hardcoded the Python path in the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)). For example, suppose the first line of the program is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

In this case, none of the previous tricks would work. Personally, I would change it to the canonical form and send a pull request to the author of the 3rd-party app.

## The bossy way: change the default Python version system-wide

While this does not really answer your question - because it affects every window and avery other user in the system - I'm mentioning it for the sake of completeness.

For example, if you are using Ubuntu you can change the default python interpreter using:

```
$ update-alternatives --config python
```

Other Linux distributions probably have something like this.

## Quick and dirty

The [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) just tells the shell to call the script using the given interpreter. You can override the shebang when calling the app as `interpreter app`:

```
$ python2 `which app_name`
```

Or:

```
$ python2 /path/to/app_name
```

You can also just edit the program and change the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)):

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
```

Note that this would change permanently the Python interpreter for that program, it is not temporary nor restricted to a particular terminal. Worst, if the program is in the global PATH, all the other users of the system will be affected. If you want to restore the old behavior, you must undo your changes.

That said, sometimes you just don't care about doing it right, you just want to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of terminal alias. **The alias will not be temporary** but it will not affect your system, so you can have a short alias like:

**alias pyt "/usr/bin/python2.7"**
in your .bashrc file inside home directory

Answer (score 0):

As the question is tagged with Linux, I assume your scripts starts with that line

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
```

This is great to allow the system to choose the current Python installation, but here your requirement is to specifically use version 2.7

So IMHO you just have to change the hashbang line to select the required version:

```
#! /path/to/python-2.7
```

Comment: This may work, but there are other very popular solutions that avoid having to modify a 3rd-party script.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Anaconda as your Python distribution, it has virtual enviroments built in. If not, use `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper` as Paul recommended.

In addition I recommend `autoenv`. With that you can automatically change your venv depending on the folder you're in. There is one for bash and one for zsh.