# How to set the default python3 to python3.9 in Linux via aliases?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, command-line

I'm a newcomer to the world of Linux. I've installed a distro in a virtual machine (elive, to be precise) and I'm starting to play around a bit. I've built from source the latest python version (3.9 at the time of writing). Now I'm trying to set it as the default python3 version (at the moment the default version is python3.2). It suffices to be set this way just for my personal shell. I've read about aliases, so I tried to use them to set the default python version. I wrote in the .bashrc the following line:

```
alias python3='python3.9'
```

I also tried:

```
alias python3=python3.9
alias python3="/usr/local/lib/python3.9"
```

I've also read that you might need to login again, so I tried it but with no results. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Elive, Debian-based : You will wreck apt, etc. administration tools if you change the default python3. ..... Better : Use / set python3.9 as python39.

Comment: An alias only affects your personal interactive shell. It's not clear if what you want is that, or something else. A common arrangement is to install the newer version in `/usr/local/bin/python` which will shadow the system-installed command with the same name. But Python needs to find its libraries etc so this alone is not yet enough.

Comment: Yes I want it to just affect my shell. I'll edit my question to make it clear. Moreover, I thought that these Debian based distros were working with python 2, so I assumed that changing the value of the python3 variable wouldn't have affected the system. Am I wrong?

Comment: Could you also post the error messages or feedbacks from the console?

Comment: There are no error messages. I modified the .bashrc file, but it doesn't seem to have any effect . When I type 'python3 --version' it says that the default one is python 3.2 whereas I want it to be python 3.9

Comment: did you check `which python3` or `alternatives python3` ?

Comment: alternatives is not recognized as a command, and 'which python3' returns me back the path: "usr/bin/python3"

Answer (score -1):

If you want better is update alternatives with this you can change default editor etc.

[How to select which version of python I am running on Linux? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35047691/how-to-select-which-version-of-python-i-am-running-on-linux)

[How to change from default to alternative Python version on Debian Linux - LinuxConfig.org](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-change-from-default-to-alternative-python-version-on-debian-linux)

or you can try this Gui version

> `sudo apt install galternatives`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It works, but that's not what I wanted. Maybe I was a bit unclear in the question. I'd prefer to see this change applied only in my personal shell.